# MySQL dual master replication -- is this scenario safe?

Tags: mysql, replication

I currently have a MySQL dual master replication (A<->B) set up and everything seems to be running swimmingly.  I drew on the basic ideas from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131225154105/http://signalboxes.net/misc/mysql-dual-master-replication/) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120222172836/http://www.hbyconsultancy.com/blog/create-a-master-master-mysql-replication-ubuntu-server-10-04-x64.html).

Server A is my web server (a VPS).  User interaction with the application leads to updates to several fields in table X (which are replicated to server B).  Server B is the heavy-lifter, where all the big calculations are done.  A cron job on server B regularly adds rows to table X (which are replicated to server A).

So server A can update (but never add) rows, and server B can add rows.  Server B can also update fields in X, but only **after** the user no longer has the ability to update that row.

What kinds of potential disasters can I expect with this scenario if I go to production with it?  Or does this seem OK?  I'm asking mostly because I'm ignorant about whether **any** simultaneous operation on the table (from either the A copy or the B copy) can cause problems or if it's just operations on *the same row* that get hairy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dual master replication is messy if you attempt to write to the same database on both masters.

One of the biggest points of contention (and high blood pressure) is the [**use of autoincrement keys**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-master.html).

As long as you remember to set [**auto_increment_increment**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) and [**auto_increment_offset**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset), you can lookup any data you want and retrieve auto_incremented ids.

You just have to remember this rule: If you read an id from serverX, you must lookup needed data from serverX using the same id.

Here is one saving grace for using dual master replication.

Suppose you have

- two databases (db1 and db2)
- two DB servers (serverA and serverB)

If you impose the following restrictions

- all writes of db1 to serverA
- all writes of db2 to serverB

then you are not required to set auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset.

*I hope my answer clarifies the good, the bad, and the ugly of using dual master replication*.

- [Here is a pictorial example of 4 masters using auto increment settings](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2006/04/20/advanced-mysql-replication.html?page=2)
- [Nice article from Percona on this subject](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/01/12/conflict-avoidance-with-auto_increment_incremen-and-auto_increment_offset/)

Comment: My understanding is that auto_increment keys are only typically relevant in the creation of new rows/records.  Since in my scenario only one master is allowed to **create** records (the other master can only update existing records), I gather from your answer that I have avoided the whole problem.  Is that correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct. This also implies you can split reads with relative impunity.

Comment: Great -- then that's the answer to my question!

Answer (score 2):

Master-master replication can be very tricky, are you sure that this is the best solution for you ? Usually it is used for load-balancing purposes (e.g. round-robin connect to your db servers) and sometimes when you want to avoid the replication lag effect. A big known issue is the auto_increment problem which is supposedly solved using different offsets and increment value.

I think you should modify your configuration to simple master-slave by making A the master and B the slave, unless I am mistaken about the requirements of your system.

Comment: If I switch to a master-slave setup where server B is the slave, how can the records which are written by server B show up in the database on A?  I could be mistaken, but I assumed that any changes made on the slave would not be replicated to the master.  Both A and B need to be able to replicate records/updates to the other server.

Comment: Also, auto_increment is not an issue since only B is creating records.  Server A only updates existing records, and never creates new ones.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can depend on 
`Percona XtraDB Cluster Feature 2: Multi-Master replication` than regular MySQL replication

> They promise the foll:

By Multi-Master I mean the ability to write to any node in your cluster and do not worry that eventually you get out-of-sync situation, as it regularly happens with regular MySQL replication if you imprudently write to the wrong server.

With Cluster you can write to any node, and the Cluster guarantees consistency of writes. That is the write is either committed on all nodes or not committed at all.

> The two important consequences of Muti-master architecture.

First: we can have several appliers working in parallel. This gives us true parallel replication. Slave can have many parallel threads, and you can tune it by variable wsrep_slave_threads

Second: There might be a small period of time when the slave is out-of-sync from master. This happens because the master may apply event faster than a slave. And if you do read from the slave, you may read data, that has not changes yet. You can see that from diagram. However you can change this behavior by using variable wsrep_causal_reads=ON. In this case the read on the slave will wait until event is applied (this however will increase the response time of the read. This gap between slave and master is the reason why this replication named “`virtually synchronous replication`”, not real “`synchronous replication`”

The described behavior of COMMIT also has the second serious implication.
If you run write transactions to two different nodes, the cluster will use an optimistic locking model.
That means a transaction will not check on possible locking conflicts during individual queries, but rather on the COMMIT stage. And you may get ERROR response on COMMIT. I am highlighting this, as this is one of incompatibilities with regular InnoDB, that you may experience. In InnoDB usually DEADLOCK and LOCK TIMEOUT errors happen in response on particular query, but not on COMMIT. Well, if you follow a good practice, you still check errors code after “COMMIT” query, but I saw many applications that do not do that.

```
So, if you plan to use Multi-Master capabilities of XtraDB Cluster, and run write transactions on several nodes, you may need to make sure you handle response on “COMMIT” query.
```

[You can find it here along with pictorial expln](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/01/19/percona-xtradb-cluster-feature-2-multi-master-replication/)

Answer (score 2):

From my rather extensive experience on this topic I can say you will regret writing to more than one master someday. It may be soon, it may not be for a long time, but it will happen. You will have two servers that each have some correct data and some wrong data, and you will either pick one as the authoritative source and throw the other away (probably without really knowing what you're throwing away) or you'll reconcile the two. No matter how you design it, you cannot eliminate the possibility of this happening, so it's a mathematical certainty that it will happen someday.

Percona (my employer) has handled probably several hundred cases of recovery after doing what you're attempting. Some of them take hours, some take weeks, one I helped with took a few months -- and that's with excellent tools to help.

Use a different replication technology or find a different way to do what you want to do.  MMM will not help -- it will bring catastrophe sooner. You cannot do this with standard MySQL replication, with or without external tools. You need a replacement replication technology such as Continuent Tungsten or Percona XtraDB Cluster.

It's often easier to just solve the real need in some other fashion and give up multi-master writes, if you want to use vanilla MySQL replication.

Answer (score 2):

and thanks for sharing my Master-Master Mysql cluster article. As Rolando clarified this configuration is not suitable for most production environment due to the limitation of autoincrement support.

The most adequate way to get a MySQL cluster is using NDB, which require at least 4 servers (2 management and 2 data nodes).

I have written a detailed article to get this running on two servers only, which is very similar to my previous article but using NDB instead.

http://www.hbyconsultancy.com/blog/mysql-cluster-ndb-up-and-running-7-4-and-6-3-on-ubuntu-server-trusty-14-04.html

Notice that I always recommend to analyse your needs and find out the most adequate solution, don't just look for available solutions and try to figure out if they fit with your needs or not.

-Hatem

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend looking into a tool that will manage this for you. Multi-master replication can be very troublesome if things go wrong.

I would suggest something like [Percona XtraDB Cluster](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster/). I've been following this project, and it looks very cool. I definitely think it will be a game changer in the MySQL world. It's still in beta though.

Comment: Thanks for the good pointers!  But it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: MMM is NOT stable and well-tested. It's a nightmare. See http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2011/05/04/whats-wrong-with-mmm/

Comment: Sorry @BaronSchwartz I should have known better than to suggest something that I didn't know much about. I've edited my answer to only suggest Percona XtraDB Cluster which I have played around with a little and trust a lot more than most of the supposedly "stable" tools out there.